# Remove whitespace after first line using SED

Tags: bash, csv, awk, sed

I am trying to edit a file with sed, my goal is to remove the white-space between the numbers but preserve it after the first word (eg Water 1983 02 13, - 1984 02 1, turns into Water,19840213,1984021)
Here is my current command:

```
awk '{print $10,$4,$2,$3,$5,$8,$6,$7}' czodiac | sed 's/Feb/02/g;s/Jan/02/g;s/–//g;s/ //g;s/,$//g'
```

output so far: Water19830213,1984021

Comment: You seem to be printing a bunch of spaces in your first command and then asking for a second command to remove them again. Just not printing them in the first place might make more sense. If you post some sample input (contents of `czodiac`) and expected output we can help you.

Comment: Thanks Ed, the answer was already provided.

Comment: **An** answer was provided. Given the question "I'm cutting myself, how do I stop the bleeding?", an answer to that specific answer would be "Put a bandaid on it" but there MIGHT be a better approach entirely...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
$ echo "$s"
Water 1983 02 13, - 1984 02 1
```

You can do:

```
$ echo "$s" | awk '{sub(/ /,","); sub(/, - /,","); gsub(/[  ]+/,"")}1'
Water,19830213,1984021
```

Comment: Thanks this worked quite well. I wasn't aware of sub within awk :D

Answer (score 0):

`sed 'h; s/[^ ]*//; s/ //g; x; s/ .*/ /; G'`